# Designer - Form Error when Moving Drop Down

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I've created a custom list which is working just fine. The next step I need to achieve is to create a custom form for users to enter in the items to this custom list. This all seemed simple enough, so I opened up SharePoint Designer and created a custom form to use with my list.

When I use the "preview in browser" button as soon as the basic form template comes up, everything work just fine. However if I move any of the drop downs around the page then when I test the form using the "preview in browser" any of the drop downs I moved don't work, any of the ones I didn't move work fine.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, obviously my moving the drop downs around the page is causing an error however I have no idea how to resolve it.

Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was that I was copying and pasting the drop down element from within designer. When I did this, I believe it altered the ASP.Net code related to that object's ID. Therefore when I clicked "save" on the form that item was not being saved, however all other entries worked.

To resolve this, I tried a copy and paste from within the code view of the drop down element and it did work... unlike when I did the save thing from